# Como criar uma só caixa de pesquisa para o Google e a Wikipédia?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google

Criei uma caixa de pesquisa com dois buttons, um para a Pesquisa Google e outro para a Pesquisa da Wikipédia. O button para o Google funciona muito bem mas não consigo fazer o mesmo para a Wikipédia. Segue o código...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Box Example 1</title>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
<!-- CSS styles for standard search box -->
<style type="text/css">
 #tfheader{
  background-color:#c3dfef;
 }
 #tfnewsearch{
  float:left;
  padding:20px;
 }
 .tftextinput{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 65px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  border:1px solid #0076a3;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
 }
 .tfbutton {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 1px #0076a3; border-right:0px;
  background: #0095cd;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee), to(#0078a5));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00adee,  #0078a5);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
 }
 .tfbutton:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #007ead;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0095cc,  #00678e);
 }
 /* Fixes submit button height problem in Firefox */
 .tfbutton::-moz-focus-inner {
   border: 0;
 }
 .tfclear{
  clear:both;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
 <div id="tfheader">
  <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search" target="_blank" >
      
   <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" id="google-search" size="21" maxlength="120"><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Pesquisa Gooogle" class="tfbutton">
          
   <button type="submit" class="tfbutton" name="q" id="wikipedia-search" formaction="http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Pesquisar/">Pesquisa Wikipedia</button>
  </form>
 <div class="tfclear"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O nome do *input* de pesquisa deve ser `search`, em vez de `q`, para funcionar com o *Wikipedia*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa usar uma linguagem *back-end* para tal. Com *JavaScript* é possível fazer o que desejas.

Isso pode ser feito tratando o evento "click" dos botões. Dessa forma podemos criar um elemento, do tipo âncora `<a>`, temporário e ativá-lo de forma automática.

**Exemplo:**

```js
/**
 * Captuar o elemento responsável por 
 * capturar o valor digitado pelo usuário
 */
const inputSearch = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]')

/**
 * Aplica um evento, do tipo "click", nos botões de pesquisa.
 * Para evitar incompatibilidades, você pode substituir o `forEach`
 * por um `for` "simples"
 */
document.querySelectorAll('#google-search, #wikipedia-search')
  .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', search))

/**
 * Função responsável por identificar o botão pressionado,
 * e enviar o usuário para o site correto.
 *
 * @param {EventTarget} event
 * @return void
 */
function search(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  const anchor = document.createElement('a')
  anchor.target = "_blank"
  anchor.href = `${event.target.getAttribute('formaction')}${encodeURI(inputSearch.value)}`
  anchor.click()
}
```

```css
#tfheader {
  background-color: #c3dfef;
}

#tfnewsearch {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tftextinput {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 65px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #0076a3;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
}

.tfbutton {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 1px #0076a3;
  border-right: 0px;
  background: #0095cd;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee), to(#0078a5));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00adee, #0078a5);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
}

.tfbutton:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #007ead;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0095cc, #00678e);
}


/* Fixes submit button height problem in Firefox */

.tfbutton::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

.tfclear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
<div id="tfheader">
  <form id="tfnewsearch">

    <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120"><br><br>

    <button type="button" class="tfbutton" id="google-search" formaction="https://www.google.com/search?q=">
      Pesquisa Google
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="tfbutton" id="wikipedia-search" formaction="http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Pesquisar?search=">
      Pesquisa Wikipedia
    </button>
  </form>
  <div class="tfclear"></div>
</div>

<small>Aqui, no StackOverflow, não vai funcionar devido à restrição.</small>
```

Comment: Obrigado Valdeir Psr você é fantástico... funciona mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

> OPÇÃO 01

no seu `input` altere o `name` para search

ficando assim: `name="search"`

> OPÇÃO 02 (COMO PHP)

Então você pode utilizar o php pra isso. com um simples formulário! eu usei o bootstrap, mas dai e só adicionar ao seu código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0-12/css/all.css" integrity="sha256-qQHUQX+gGGYfpC7Zdni08sr+h0ymXr0avmIASucY4FM=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>Formulario!</title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <form action="resultado_caixadebusca.php" target="_blank" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Sua pesquisa abaixo</label>
              <input type="text" name="termo_pesquisa" class="form-control" placeholder="Oque deseja ?">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="tipo_pesquisa" value="1" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fab fa-google"></i> Pesquisa Gooogle</button>
            <button type="submit" name="tipo_pesquisa" value="2" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fab fa-wikipedia-w"></i> Pesquisa Wikipedia</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
    <!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

E no resultado_caixadebusca.php voce adiciona o:

```
if ($_POST['tipo_pesquisa'] === '1') {
  $linkpesquisa = "https://www.google.com/search?q=".$_POST['termo_pesquisa']."";
  header('Location: '.$linkpesquisa.'');
}
if ($_POST['tipo_pesquisa'] === '2') {
  $linkpesquisa = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?sort=relevance&search=".$_POST['termo_pesquisa']."";
  header('Location: '.$linkpesquisa.'');
}
```

Assim ele vai pegar o `$_POST` enviado pelo formulário adicionar a URL e redirecionar.

Comment: Você também pode usar metado $_GET, só alterar.

Comment: Obrigado Matheus Vitor, mas não consigo colocar a funcionar... aparece isto: "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/wid/corampopulo.pt/resultado_caixadebusca.php:6) in /home2/wid/corampopulo.pt/resultado_caixadebusca.php on line 10"

Comment: E alguma coisa em seu server que não está permitindo o $_POST, tente mudar pra o $_GET mesmo.

Comment: na pagina do php deixei somente assim: http://prntscr.com/ospuir

Comment: Como e php eu não consigo ver.. somente com o arquivo consigo ver, você tem team View ?

Comment: Mude tudo $_POST para $_GET

Comment: Mude no PHP e no HTML para GET

Comment: Mudei para "get" na pagina html e no php e vai para uma nova pagina mas não mostra nada, nem sequer aparece o endereço de busca no website do google ou da wikipedia.